# My wall is too thick for a 1/4 inch snap toggler

Tags: drywall-anchor

I am trying to install a pot rack and it calls for two 1/4 inch snap toggler screws.  I used a 1/2 inch drill bit but the wall appears to be thicker then the drill bit and Im not sure what's beyond the drill bit point.  So my toggle screws will not open.  not sure what to do here.  can I just use a 1/2 inch anchor screw ?

Comment: Are you sure you have not hit a stud?  Was wood coming out?  What age is your house?

Comment: If the wall is stone then an expanding anchor will work. But why are you trying to use a drywall anchor on a wall that may not be drywall?